# how come mock doesn't return null when no subbing defined

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I looked at mockito official doc

and I don't understand:

```
1. Let's verify some behaviour!

01
//Let's import Mockito statically so that the code looks clearer
02
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
03

04
//mock creation
05
List mockedList = mock(List.class);
06

07
//using mock object
08
mockedList.add("one");
09
mockedList.clear();
10


11
//verification
12
verify(mockedList).add("one");
13
verify(mockedList).clear();
Once created, mock will remember all interactions. Then you can selectively verify whatever interaction you are interested in.

2. How about some stubbing?

01
//You can mock concrete classes, not only interfaces
02
LinkedList mockedList = mock(LinkedList.class);
03

04
//stubbing
05
when(mockedList.get(0)).thenReturn("first");
06
when(mockedList.get(1)).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());
07

08
//following prints "first"
09
System.out.println(mockedList.get(0));
10

11
//following throws runtime exception
12
System.out.println(mockedList.get(1));
13

14
//following prints "null" because get(999) was not stubbed
15
System.out.println(mockedList.get(999));
```

how come

`08
mockedList.add("one");`

doesn't return null, as no stubbing was defined.

as seen here:

`14
//following prints "null" because get(999) was not stubbed
15
System.out.println(mockedList.get(999));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

08
mockedList.add("one");

is add not get like 15

Comment: but `add()` also wasn't defined. it's not an error?

Comment: so we don't have to stub anything that returns "void" but only non-void methods?

Comment: On line 5 List mockedList = mock(List.class); an Mock for the Collection List is created. And List has the methods add and get. get(999) returns null because no value 999 is added to the list.

Comment: verify(mockedobject).somemethod  is used to verify that somemethod is called on the mocked object, with the listed parameters, so its like an assertThat(mockedobject.somemethod().wasCalled() )  - if that was even possible.- verify confirms that you tried to add("one") to your mocked object but has nothing to do with the contents of said mock.